# If condition is not working in bash

Tags: shell

in the below code its directly going to else condition than if

```
#!/bin/bash
var=0
if [ "$var" -eq "0" ]
   then
   echo $var
else
   echo $var
fi
```

Comment: Your code looks fine... except the `if` and `else` conditions have the same result. How can you tell the difference?

Comment: Except for the output issue as noted by @eigenchris, the  code that you have shown, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code demonstrably works **exactly** as given, with no changes whatsoever.

Putting it in a script called `testscript`, and running `PS4=':$LINENO+' bash -x testscript` (to print each command invoked preceded by the line number in the source file that it came from), one gets the following output:

```
:2+var=0
:3+'[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
:5+echo 0
0
```

Now, let's look at the line numbers in that trace, against the line numbers in the original source file:

```
#!/bin/bash                # line 1
var=0                      # line 2 -- :2+var=3
if [ "$var" -eq "0" ]      # line 3 -- :3+'[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
   then                    # line 4
   echo $var               # line 5 -- :5+echo 0
else                       # line 6
   echo $var               # line 7
fi
```

...and the fact that we went to line 2, line 3, and line 5 in that order means that we actually took the truth branch, not the `else` branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
var=0
if [ "$var" -eq "0" ]
   then
   echo $var
   echo "Hello"
else
   echo $var
   echo "ELSE"
fi
```

It will print: 0 Hello

> means it is going if loop only. Check once